# Using set-builder notation in an unusual way for more concise expressions in a definition. Good style?

Tags: proof-writing, notation, terminology, philosophy

What do you think about the following usage of the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) $\{ x \mid P(x) \}$? Let $Y = \{ p_1, \ldots, p_n \}$ be $n$ objects and $A,B$ subsets of $Y$. Define a function from $\{1,\ldots,n\} \times X$, where $X$ is a set, to subsets of $Y$ in the following way
for each $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$:
$$
 f(i, x) = \begin{cases}
  \{ p_i \mid x \in A \} \cup \{ p_{i+1} \mid x \in B \} & \text{if } i \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}, \\
 \{ p_i \mid x \in A \} & \text{if } i = n.
\end{cases}
$$
In the more "traditional" notation it would be written
as:
$$
 f(i, x) = \begin{cases}
 \{ p_i, p_{i+1} \} & \text{if } x \in A \cap B, i \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\} \\
 \{ p_i \}          & \text{if } x \in A \setminus B \text{ or } i = n, x \in A \\
 \emptyset          & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
The first variant is probably not how set-builder notation is intended to be used, as it basically reduces to $\{ p_i \mid TRUE \} = \{p_i\}$ or $\{ p_i \mid FALSE \} = \emptyset$ depending on the value of $x$. I think it is valid to write expressions like that.
But what do you think style-wise? Do you think such a usage should be avoided? In my opinion the first version is a little more concise, but this is just my personal opinion. Maybe you disagree...

Comment: To give a simpler example, if you want to define $f(x)=\{3\}$ if $x\in A$ and $f(x)=\varnothing$ if $x\notin A$, how about using "set-builder" notation and writing $f(x)=\{3|x\in A\}$? I don't like it but maybe it's just me.

Comment: I do like the use of $\{3\mid x\in A\}$. This notation also has the advantage that does not assume excluded middle. It's totally unrelated, I know, but it is the correct way to define these things in intuitionistic set theory.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I was not aware that this notation is actually used in intuitionistic set theory. I would be glad if you can give more details on that btw.